# "Invalid status code: undefined" with uploading an image in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer, cloudinary

So I've followed the tutorial exactly. The code seems to function in this order:

1. Form Page is rendered and sends data in POST request to /api/v1/users/signup/
2. From there it hits the userRoutes.js

For some reason if I submit the data *without* uploading an image it will work. It will get to the userRoutes.js and it will console log, but if I upload an image it will throw `RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined`

This is the form code:

```
<form action="/api/v1/users/signup/" novalidate method="POST" class="validated-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form_group">
    <label for="name">Name</Address></label>
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="user[name]">
</div>
<div class="form_group">
    <label for="email">Email Address</Address></label>
    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="email" name="user[email]">
</div>
<div class="form_group">
    <label for="password">Password</Address></label>
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" name="user[password]">
</div>
<div class="form_group">
    <label for="passwordConfirm">Password Confirm</Address></label>
    <input id="passwordConfirm" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="user[passwordConfirm]">
</div>
<div class="form_group">
    <input type="file" id="image" name="image" multiple>

</div>
HELLO!
```

This is where cloudinary is:

```
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
const { CloudinaryStorage } = require('multer-storage-cloudinary');

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET
});

const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
    cloudinary,
    params: {
        folder: 'YelpCamp',
        allowedFormats: ['jpeg', 'png', 'jpg']
    }
});

module.exports = {
    cloudinary,
    storage
}
```

This is userRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');
const authController = require('../controllers/authController');
const multer = require('multer');
const { storage } = require('../cloudinary');
const upload = multer({ storage });

const router = express.Router();

// authController.signUp
// Signup, login, and logout
router.post('/signup', upload.array('image'), (req, res) => {
    console.log('NO ERROR YET')
    console.log(req.body, req.files);
    res.send("IT WORKED");
});
```

Error:

```
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: undefined
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:248:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (C:\Users\iii\Desktop\amazon-clone-master\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:44:26)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:239:8)
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:650:9)
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:762:5)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\iii\Desktop\amazon-clone-master\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:221:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\iii\Desktop\amazon-clone-master\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at sendErrorDev (C:\Users\iii\Desktop\amazon-clone-master\controllers\errorController.js:32:39)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\iii\Desktop\amazon-clone-master\controllers\errorController.js:93:5)
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\iii\Desktop\amazon-clone-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\iii\Desktop\amazon-clone-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
    at C:\Users\iii\Desktop\amazon-clone-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\iii\Desktop\amazon-clone-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\iii\Desktop\amazon-clone-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at C:\Users\iii\Desktop\amazon-clone-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
    at next (C:\Users\iii\Desktop\amazon-clone-master\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
```

**Other than that I can't see why it's not working.**

It might have something to do with my error handler:

```
const sendErrorDev = (err, req, res) => {
  // API
  if (req.originalUrl.startsWith('/api')) {
    return res.status(err.statusCode)
    .json({
      status: err.status,
      error: err,
      message: err.message,
      stack: err.stack,
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the part about not posting *picture* of *text*.

Comment: OKay I'll fix it now, sorry thanks!

Comment: "So I've followed the tutorial exactly" Which tutorial?

Comment: "I would post them all here but I feel it's very confronting to see it all on one question". We actively encourage you to post the code in the question rather than as images. It's much easier to replicate locally or copy details for searching.

Comment: Well It's from Colt Steeles udemy course. I followed the upload images part exactly. It's just strange it all works fine provided I don't upload an image

Comment: What is the upload.array('image') here? Cloudinary can only upload one image at a time and here is the link to the node uploader method-https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_and_video_upload